# Фразеологизмы и придаточные предложения

Tags: фразеология, пунктуация, синтаксис

Он сделал работу так, что комар носа не подточит.
Ответьте пожалуйста, является ли предложение с фразеологизмом сложноподчиненным и нужна ли запятая.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю, что да. Это сложноподчиненное предложение. Есть главное предложение (с указательным словом *так*), есть придаточная часть,  присоединяемая подчинительным союзом *что*. Придаточное образа действия поясняет указательное слово так (как именно так сделал?). Запятая перед что нужна. Другое дело, что мы не можем в составе фразеологизма выделить подлежащее комар и сказуемое  не подточит, комар носа не подточит - это цельное сочетание, обозначает, что работа сделана  очень точно, без изъянов, не подкопаешься, не придерешься.

Comment: Дела в величайшем порядке… комар носа не подточит. (А. Серафимович.)
Тогда без союза "что" предложение уже простое? И чем выражен фразеологизм в этом случае? Если я подразумеваю, что дела отличные , то определение? Как подчеркивать? А если я подразумеваю, что дела были сделаны "как?", то уже в роли обстоятельства?

Comment: Простите, не сразу увидела комментарий. Да,  без союза "что" предложение не будет сложноподчиненным. В вашем примере скорее сказуемое, чем определение.